# Passing ACL messages between jade remote platforms

Tags: java, agent, agents-jade

I need to pass an ACL message between 2 jade platforms. I implemented my code to pass messages between agents in the same container. That works fine. But I could not develop that code to pass messages between remote platforms.

Below is what I implemented for the agents in the same container. In the sender agent code the result[] only gets the agents in the same platform.

What am I missing?
Is there any method to get the list of agents in the remote platform?

Sender agent

```
DFAgentDescription temp = new DFAgentDescription();
    try
    {
        //DFAgentDescription[] result = DFService.search(this,temp);
        SearchConstraints sc = new SearchConstraints();
        DFAgentDescription[] result=DFService.search(this,temp,sc);
        ACLMessage acl = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);

        System.out.println("Agents: ");
        for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++)
        {
            if(result[i].getName().getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase("R1"))
            {
                acl.addReceiver(result[i].getName());
                System.out.print(" , "+result[i].getName().getLocalName());
            }
        }

        acl.setContent("Hello...");
        this.send(acl);
        System.out.println("Message Sent...");
    }
    catch(FIPAException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error !: "+e);
    }
```

Receiver agent

```
addBehaviour(new CyclicBehaviour()
    {
        public void action()
        {
            ACLMessage  msg = myAgent.receive();
            if(msg != null)
            {
                if(msg.getPerformative()== ACLMessage.REQUEST)
                {
                    String content = msg.getContent();
                    if ((content != null))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Received Request from "+msg.getSender().getLocalName());
                        System.out.println("Received Message : "+content);
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        block();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                block();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
AID r=new AID("agent-name@platform",AID.ISGUID);
r.addAddresses("http://192.168.1.1:7778/acc");
acl.addReceiver(r);
acl.setContent("Hello.!");
this.send(acl);
System.out.println("\nMessage Sent to "+r);
```

Instead my local IP use your own IP or hostname.

Comment: agent-name@platform Is it sender or receiver agent name?

Comment: Yeah it is agent's local name.

Comment: Say you have to get an address from a message which was sent by an agent from another machine. How to get that agents address?