# jade agents data communication

Tags: java, agents-jade

My project is to create agents that represent buses to solve a power flow system using the gauss seidel method. The difficulty right now is that since different buses hold different information, they will need to send each other information in order to perform the calculation. My approach is to define variables to represent known values like voltage in each agent then deliver them across other agents when necessary. However since I'm very new to programming in general especially JADE, I'm having trouble getting these agents to share information. How do I implement that? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. Otherwise it's not really possible to get a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, "yellow pages service" will help you. You should register every agent during setup and search them when you need. For example (from "developing multi-agent systems with Jade").

registration:

```
protected void setup() {
... // Register the book-selling service in the yellow pages 
   DFAgentDescription dfd = new DFAgentDescription(); 
   dfd.setName(getAID()); 
   ServiceDescription sd = new ServiceDescription(); 
   sd.setType("Book-selling"); 
   sd.setName(getLocalName()+"-Book-selling"); 
   dfd.addServices(sd); 
   try { 
       DFService.register(this, dfd);
   } catch (FIPAException fe) { 
      fe.printStackTrace(); } ...
   }
```

and the search:

```
DFAgentDescription template = new DFAgentDescription(); 
ServiceDescription sd = new ServiceDescription(); 
sd.setType("Book-selling"); 
template.addServices(sd); 
try { 
    DFAgentDescription[] result = DFService.search(myAgent, template); 
} catch (FIPAException fe) { 
    fe.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For basic messages please refer to the linke that will. This is a basic solution though and does not scale well.
[Passing ACL messages between jade remote platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793308/passing-acl-messages-between-jade-remote-platforms)

For a cleaner solution follow the following steps:

1. Register agents and services with the directory facilitator (DF). YOu can find reccommendations on how to do this in this thread and on others. (Message from agent supplying service -> DF)
2. Request service and agent from DF. Again this can be found 
   (Message from agent requesting service -> DF)
   (DF-> responds with service supplier info)
3. Send a custom message to the agent supplying the service.
   In this message you will embed you info.

I typically use XML or string manipulation:

```
AID r=new AID("agent-name@platform",AID.ISGUID);
r.addAddresses("http://192.168.1.1:7778/acc");
acl.addReceiver(r);
acl.setContent("time=10:30");
this.send(acl);
System.out.println("\nMessage Sent to "+r);
```